# Benchmarking Tasks on the main thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I would like to compare the performance difference between using a `Task` and not in the example below. I know that the tasks have executed successfully since I can make use of their results before I stop the second timer.

I would like to know why my last example writes `0` ms:

```
private Task<List<ACTION>> GetActions()
{
   return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            return context.ACTION.ToList();
        }
    });
}
```

-

```
var sw1 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();
var sync1 = context.ACTION.ToList();
var sync2 = context.ACTION.ToList();
sw1.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds); //4XX MS

var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();
var t1 = GetActions();
var t2 = GetActions();
var tasks = new Task[] { t1, t2 };
Task.WaitAll(tasks); 
sw2.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds); //0 MS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you start the `sw1` in the second sample as well.

```
var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();
```

Comment: *facepalm*, that what happens when you're getting tired. Thanks :)